# Nothing is being written to csv file windows store app

Tags: c#, csv, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm using the following code to write to a .csv file.

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile newFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("myFile.csv", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
tb.Text = storageFolder.Path;

String z = null;// content to be written
z += ("Hi" + " > " + "THAT");
z += (",Testing\n");

await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(newFile, z);
```

This code works **perfectly** for me (I open the file using Microsoft Office). But when one of my friend (**who is French**) uses the same app, the file is created with **"ÐÏà¡±á ;  þÿ     þÿÿÿ 
þÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ"**, application crashes, and OPEN OFFICE cannot open that file.

The error shown by Open office:

> The myFile.csv file is corrupt and can't be opened. OpenOffice can try to repair the file.
>   The corruption may be the resulta of a manipulation of the document or of a deterioration of the structrue of the document due to the transmission of data.
>   We recommende not to trust the content of the repaired document. The macro execution is unactivated.
>   Should OpenOffice repair the file? Yes No

If you want to look at the app (optional), here is the link: http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/0ba7a9df-59dd-4410-9ecb-67eac3e81b63.  Click on export button on the bottom app bar to export file.

Comment: `.csv` files are intended to be plaintext; what happens when you open the created file in notepad?

Comment: It being urgent... doesn't really change anything. Honestly, it just makes me upset, because its like saying "My question is more important than all those other ones". Please refrain from putting that kind of information in your posts (the "[Tough One]" semi-tag is similarly useless). Finally, tags don't belong in titles.

Comment: In many European localizations, csv files are actually delimited by semicolons.

Comment: @admdrew, When friend of mine having his language selected as french opens file in his computer nothing is displayed.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanQadri Is your friend opening the file in notepad (not Word/Excel/OpenOffice/etc)?

Comment: @admdrew, Yes he sees nothing when he opens in notepad.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanQadri Is it possible to have your friend debug/step through this code in his environment?

Comment: Just a note to anyone thinking about notepad, office or any other app: if the files is 0 bytes then it is completely empty, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @admdrew, he's my client actually. He doesn't have visual studio as well.

Comment: @Silvermind, why is it empty on his computer, just because he's French?

And I get perfect file in all computers having English as default language.

Comment: @Silvermind Agreed; I was just trying to rule out any potential confusion between me and the OP, if the OP had meant the file *looked* empty in OpenOffice, instead of determining the actual filesize.

Comment: I think it's some sort of encoding problem, that my file cannot be interpreted by French language's OpenOffice

Comment: Can you try using the [version of `WriteTextAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701510.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) that allows you to specify an encoding?

Comment: @dbc, which version should I specify in encoding?[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.unicodeencoding)

Comment: @MuhammadRehanQadri If the file is empty, opening is not the actual issue, but writing to it is and encoding should not be a problem here. Don't you get any exceptions? Is this the actual code?

Comment: @Silvermind, the file has "ÐÏà¡±á ;  þÿ     þÿÿÿ 
þÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ" written in it. Let me update this in question.

Comment: @Muhammad Rehan Qadri - now that looks like an encoding problem.  But i'm not sure of the correct one to use, but it's probably Utf8.  Test it on your machine, make sure Utf8 works, then let the customer try it.

Comment: hmm, you're an angle dbc, let me try.